# Cross domain open kmz files in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-earth, kmz

I have a problem with opening kmz file via google earth api. It works fine when  I provide static link to the file on server:

```
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, 'http://10.122.150.183:8008/test.kmz', checkForCoordinates);
```

But when I change link to the file on another domain (which is WCF service) : `'https://10.122.150.183:4431/Uploads/1/test.kmz'`, file doesn't open in google earth. I've tried another solution: to provide kmz files dynamically from ASP.Net MVC controller, returning:

```
return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz kmz", fileName);
```

It works fine if I try to get it from browser's address bar, but when I provide link to the action in `fetchKml` method, the action even doesn't inovoke.

Any suggestions on how to open kmz files from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track by assigning MIME types. Have seen the info on this page
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#kml_server

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the Kmz file generator in wcf. The service returns Stream type object with, outgoing response content type set to "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz".

The code look like this

```
public class Kmz
{
    public static Stream Generate(string stringKml, string fileName)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddEntry(fileName, stringKml);
            zip.Save(stream);
        }

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz";

        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript's iframe or script ways to load the kml content, these two ways allow you to load resource from different domain, and then use the parseKml function to parse the kml content and add it into your earth.

hopefully it helps.